# Appengine Projection Queries with JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

the appengine projection queries look interesting.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries

i am using the DN JPA plugin and i got no idea how to do a projection query.

simple query.

```
select from PositionUser p where p.friends = :userKey
```

the Entity has the list a a lazy fetch.

```
@Entity
public class Data{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;    
private String nickName;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String email;

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY
private List<Key> friends;
```

i want my do a query on my entity without serializing the List.

Q1.is the lazy fetch the mechanism for projection query in JPA/appengine?

Q2.how do i know if a projection query is operational?

thanks

-lp

Comment: there are lots of docs for how to specify a result clause in JPQL (which is what projection is), so what happens when you do that?

Comment: @NeilStockton you are correct. i dont know how i missed this.